# After deleting all pictures, internal storage view still shows over 6GB of pictures

Tags: internal-storage, nexus-5, 6.0-marshmallow, images

I connected my nexus 5 to my computer in MTP mode and deleted all pictures I could find. But after deleting all pictures (I looked in the DCIM, pictures, panoramas, whatsapp pictures), it shows still over 6GB in pictures in the internal storage view.

I even used the windows search to search for *.jpg and *.png files, but besides a handul of small files, I cannot find the missing 6GB of pictures. How can I find where the other pictures are located?

Comment: It's possible that the storage left hasn't been recalculated. Restart your device and see if that does anything.

Comment: another explanation is Gallery application buffering old images in .thumbnails file. See if You have 'show hidden files' enabled in options, and next see also Settings => applications => Gallery : how much memory is listed under "data"? (if it is huge - cleaning cache would help)